# How store values together after scrape

Tags: selenium, dictionary, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I am able to scrape individual fields off a website, but would like to map the title to the time.

The fields "have their own class, so I am struggling on how to map the time to the title.

A dictionary would work, but how would i structure/format this dictionary so that it stores values on a line by line basis?

url for reference - https://ash.confex.com/ash/2021/webprogram/STUDIO.html

**expected output:**

9:00 AM-9:30 AM, Defining Race, Ethnicity, and Genetic Ancestry

11:00 AM-11:30 AM, Definitions of Structural Racism

etc

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
import time


driver.get('https://ash.confex.com/ash/2021/webprogram/STUDIO.html')
time.sleep(3)
page_source = driver.page_source
soup=BeautifulSoup(page_source,'html.parser')


productlist=soup.find_all('div',class_='itemtitle')
for item in productlist:
    for eachLine in item.find_all('a',href=True):
        title=eachLine.text
        print(title)
times=driver.find_elements_by_class_name("time")
for t in times:
    print(t.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium is an overkill here. Website didn't use any dynamic content, so you can scrape it with Python `requests` and `BeautifulSoup`. Here is a code how to achieve it. You need to query `productlist` and `times` separately and then iterate using indexes to be able to get both items at once. I put in `range()` length of an `productlist` because I assuming that both `productlist` and `times` will have equal length.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://ash.confex.com/ash/2021/webprogram/STUDIO.html'

res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'html.parser')

productlist = soup.select('div.itemtitle > a')
times = soup.select('.time')

for iterator in range(len(productlist)):
    row = times[iterator].text + ", " + productlist[iterator].text
    print(row)
```

Note: `soup.select()` gather items by css.

Comment: btw what is > a' supposed to mean? what if i wanted to get the href/link for every productlist. how would i write that?

Comment: It means that we are choosing `<a>` item which is directly inside `<div>` with class `itemtitle`. You can get `href` of a link according to the code above using `productlist[iterator]["href"]`

Comment: Arrow notation may be better described here: https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#child-combinators

Comment: Nice approach, how would this be approached if the two fields are not of equal length?