# Webscrape - Fields of different length

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

The current code scrapes individual fields, but I would like to map the time and the titles together.

Since the webpage does not have the time and titles in the same class, how would this mapping occur?

Piggy-backing off this question -[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69866572/how-store-values-together-after-scrape) (My question uses an example where the time and title is not of equal length)

Website for reference:
https://ash.confex.com/ash/2021/webprogram/WALKS.html

**Sample Expected Output:**

*5:00 PM-6:00 PM, ASH Poster Walk on Geriatric Hematology: Selecting the Right Treatment for the Patient, Not Just the Disease*

*5:00 PM-6:00 PM, ASH Poster Walk on Healthcare Quality Improvement*

etc

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://ash.confex.com/ash/2021/webprogram/WALKS.html'

res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'html.parser')

productlist = soup.select('div.itemtitle > a')
times = soup.select('.time')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be an alternative:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://ash.confex.com/ash/2021/webprogram/WALKS.html'

#this is to get the url part before the last "/"
base_url = url.rsplit("/", 1)[0]

res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'html.parser')

productlist = soup.select('div.itemtitle > a')
#times = soup.select('.time')

for a in productlist:
  title = a.text.strip()
  time = a.find_previous('h3').text.strip()
  date = a.find_previous('h4').text.strip()
  page = a['href'].strip()
  #sep = "/" is the separator between each parameter
  #end = "makes the double linebreak when print function is done"
  print(title, date, time, base_url + page, sep = "\n", end = "\n\n")
```

OUTPUT

```
ASH Poster Walk on What's Hot in Sickle Cell Disease
Wednesday, December 15, 2021
10:00 AM-11:00 AM
https://ash.confex.com/ash/2021/webprogramSession20816.html

ASH Poster Walk on Geriatric Hematology: Selecting the Right Treatment for the Patient, Not Just the Disease
Wednesday, December 15, 2021
5:00 PM-6:00 PM
https://ash.confex.com/ash/2021/webprogramSession20695.html

ASH Poster Walk on Healthcare Quality Improvement
Wednesday, December 15, 2021
5:00 PM-6:00 PM
https://ash.confex.com/ash/2021/webprogramSession21143.html

ASH Poster Walk on Natural Killer Cell-Based Immunotherapy
Wednesday, December 15, 2021
5:00 PM-6:00 PM
https://ash.confex.com/ash/2021/webprogramSession20655.html

ASH Poster Walk on Pediatric Non-malignant Hematology Highlights
Wednesday, December 15, 2021
5:00 PM-6:00 PM
https://ash.confex.com/ash/2021/webprogramSession20721.html

ASH Poster Walk on Clinical Trials In Progress
Thursday, December 16, 2021
10:00 AM-11:00 AM
https://ash.confex.com/ash/2021/webprogramSession20589.html

ASH Poster Walk on Financial Toxicity in Hematologic Malignancies
Thursday, December 16, 2021
10:00 AM-11:00 AM
https://ash.confex.com/ash/2021/webprogramSession20663.html

ASH Poster Walk on Diversity, Equity, and Inclusion in Hematologic Malignancies and Cell Therapy
Thursday, December 16, 2021
5:00 PM-6:00 PM
https://ash.confex.com/ash/2021/webprogramSession20809.html

ASH Poster Walk on Emerging Research in Immunotherapies
Thursday, December 16, 2021
5:00 PM-6:00 PM
https://ash.confex.com/ash/2021/webprogramSession20805.html

ASH Poster Walk on the Spectrum of Hemostasis and Thrombosis Research
Thursday, December 16, 2021
5:00 PM-6:00 PM
https://ash.confex.com/ash/2021/webprogramSession20821.html
```

Comment: awesome, and how would you find the href of each title using this method?

Comment: is it possible to include the href/link of each title to each iteration of 'a' as well?\

Comment: Great solution. @VoidS to get the href just do `a['href']`

Comment: Nice.  There i added the @pedro-maia changes

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
content = soup.find('div', {"class": "content"})
times = content.find_all("h3")
output = []
for i,h3 in enumerate(times):
    for j in h3.next_siblings:
        if j.name:
            if j.name == "h3":
                break
            j = j.text.replace('\n', '')
            output.append(f"{times[i].text}, {j}")
print(output)
```

Comment: would you happen to know how to include the href/url into each iteration of 'a' of the user aboves post?